# Consume WSDL Web Service with F# .Net core

Tags: c#, f#, wsdl, .net-core, fsharp.data.typeproviders

There is possible to use F# with .net core to consume a SOAP Web service, with authentication by .pfx certificate and password?

A have a list of SOAP Services, but they change the url by the company I need to communicate. And I don't want to make manual the assign of the service. I was doing in C# on this way [Create SOAP clients dynamic by WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754776/create-soap-clients-dynamic-by-wsdl), but not work in .net core.

Comment: It's SOAP, not WSDL Web Services. `.pfx` doesn't mean anything, you probably mean Basic authentication. .NET Core is only supported in the current Release Candidate of F#, which means the current stable version doesn't run on .NET Core. Proxy generation is a job for either Visual Studio or `svcutil`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried to explain bether

Comment: you missed the point. Are you sure that what you ask is even possible? You can't run F# on .NET Core unless it's a pre-release version.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry.